# The exact duplicate box has gone for a walk-about on beta sites

Tags: bug, design, beta-phase

[image: Misplaced duplicate box]

As of today the paste your duplicate URL box in the close dialogue seems to have been shifted out of position on Grainy themed sites.  I'm experiencing this on Biology and Chemistry, in both the review queue and from the normal question view. When I type in a duplicate the tails of the long letters in 'type or paste a question link or numeric question id' field are still visible below the link.

It's not happening on MSO or gaming so I think it's probably just for beta sites.

I'm using Chrome `23.0.1271.97 m` and my zoom is set to 100%.

Comment: I see this regularly on Ask Different using Mobile Safari (iOS 6) and the full site design, so it might be more widely distributed than just beta sites.